# Why is this code not giving the correct reference to my firebase firestore database collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to use unsubscribe onSnapshot to listen to messages in a React Native chat app with firebase SDK, and the onSnapshot seems to work but it is always returning an empty array.

I believe this is because the reference I am giving it to my collection in the firestore database is not correct, but I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. I've tested firebase.firestore() in some queries and it always seems to return the right values, but I can't seem to use it as a ref correctly.

Below are the images of the ref in my firebase file, the onSnapshot in the chat screen file, and my firestore database.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

The `messages` in your screenshot is not a collection, but an array field inside the `threads` document. So you should [listen to that specific document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes), and then access its `messages` field.